# Calculated Member in SSAS filter by dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I have attached an image of a report based on a SSAS cube that I have created so far. I want to create a "Calculated Member" (Confirmed Current Count") in my cube that basically combines the "Confirmed~~" measure with the "Current" member of the "As of Day" dimension. This way, I will be able to show a couple of other measure. Please see the second screenshot on what I have so far. However, BIDS is telling me that the syntax for SCOPE is incorrect. What am I doing wrong? Should I be doing this differently?

[image: report]

[image: MDX syntax]

Comment: Trust me, I have spent quite a bit of time on Google searching for a solution. I don't think there is an issue with MDX, but as Frank pointed out below, I might have to use the "Script view" in BIDS to create this calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of the user interface: It allows you to only enter one statement into the "Expression" box. But you entered five. You would have to enter each `SCOPE` and `END SCOPE`, as well as the assignment to `This` into a separate calculation.

It may be easier to enter this type of calculation in Script view, where you see the complete calculation script as one long text, and not each statement in a separate dialog. You can switch between these views with a button in the toolbar.